# Should imprecise tags be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, specific-question

This [stackoverflow question about the Ruby language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398919/what-does-the-equals-symbol-mean-after-a-method-definition) includes tags for "ruby" and "ruby-on-rails", although the question is exclusively about a Ruby language feature and has nothing to do with the Rails framework.

Do we leave the imprecise Rails tag in case it helps a Rails beginner solve his problem or do we remove it in the interest of brevity?  If we leave it, then should we leave any conceivably pertinent tags, regardless of applicability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove unneeded tags. Beginners tend to add as many tags as they can think of, simply because they don't really know enough about the topic. Removing unnecessary tags might actually help them out in the long run. Also, a comment explaining why a tag was removed might also be useful.

Answer (score 3):

I think that tags which are unrelated to the question should be removed.