# When are question tags irrelevant and should be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags

A question can only have a max of 5 tags. Does it make sense to always go by "the more tags the better" even when some of chosen tags are:

- barely related to the subject;
- extremely detailed
- very unpopular (0  followers).
- and question already has 1 or more tags which describe it well?

I'm talking about situations when question has 1 or more well-suited tags, and the rest don't have a real purpose (in my opinion).

Examples:

[Fixed panels while scrolling on a centered design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552177/fixed-panels-while-scrolling-on-a-centered-design)
This css related question has **fixed** tag. Should this tag be removed from the question? Technically, a tag could be created for each css attribute, each php function... See where I'm going?

Another example would be **mysql_real_escape_string** tag for php/mysql related question.

**error** tag. How can this tag be useful? It doesn't tell anything.

[css3-transitions-not-working-on-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551645/css3-transitions-not-working-on-button) **css-transitions** tag used here. Should it be kept or removed?

In all situations mentioned above, I would opt for removing the bolded tag. But maybe my understanding of tagging questions is wrong.

I found a similar question ([should-imprecise-tags-be-removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84361/should-imprecise-tags-be-removed)), but it's not as detailed as I'd wish.

Shed some light/share your thoughts :)

Comment: **AAAAAAA!** [tag:mysql-real-escape-string] is a *real thing*!?  For Pete's sake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Improper tagging usually falls under:

1. Unnecessary, extraneous tags (like [error](/questions/tagged/error) on the MySQL question).
2. Improper tag due to shared nomenclature (your [fixed](/questions/tagged/fixed) example or [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas) on a WPF question).
3. "Meta" tags.

Extraneous tags should be removed, improper tags should be removed, and "meta" tags should be removed.

Now in the case of [css-transitions](/questions/tagged/css-transitions), it may be worthwhile letting it ride to see if enough questions pop up regarding CSS Transitions.

Comment: Why should 'Extraneous' tags be removed? If they are not relevant, its understandable, but if they are relevant... (This also depends on the varying opinion of which tags are extraneous...)