# Trogdor, your services are requested

Tags: support, meta

Here is a list I've compiled of Meta-tags that could be [burninated](http://www.ebaumsworld.com/video/watch/786970/):

[close-votes](/questions/tagged/close-votes)
[tag-sets](/questions/tagged/tag-sets)
[page-layout](/questions/tagged/page-layout)
[withdrawn](/questions/tagged/withdrawn)
[users-page-2.0](/questions/tagged/users-page-2.0)
[user-tab](/questions/tagged/user-tab)
[wrong-answers-count](/questions/tagged/wrong-answers-count)
[voters-page](/questions/tagged/voters-page)
[bling](/questions/tagged/bling)
[top-buttons](/questions/tagged/top-buttons)
[app-offline](/questions/tagged/app-offline)
[burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request)

For these I was going with [this ref](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97182)

**Update:** I'll remove [oy](/questions/tagged/oy)[meta-means-murder](/questions/tagged/meta-means-murder) from my requests given the comments and the fact that I *had never scrolled down* on the maintenance page...  Meta-means-murder.  Check.  Ok.  Got that now.

Comment: note - I reallly wanted to create a [meta-tag:burninate-request] tag...

Comment: meme tags should be preserved lest Meta lose its slightly irreverent air.

Comment: Shouldn't close-votes just be a synonym for [meta-tag:vote-to-close], so it helps guide users who might use it?

Comment: The way it was used was to imply how many close votes one had -- I.e. 'Count' of vote-to-close which is why I didn't suggest it as a synonym, but I'd say either way works for me.

Comment: @M. Tibbits: I had previously created a burnination-request tag, and that got ... burninated.

Comment: Feel free to add this tag to your post.  I'm a fan.  If you'd prefer [meta-tag:burnination-request] instead of [meta-tag:burninate-request] that would be fine with me, I didn't add the tag to my post someone else did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oy!

Comment: must...resist...upvote...

Answer (score 6):

I think the [tag-sets](/questions/tagged/tag-sets) tag is probably a good tag, that just hasn't been applied to the questions it needs to yet.

For [oy](/questions/tagged/oy) you'll need to get permission from [Rebecca Chernoff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140548/rebecca-chernoff).

Comment: lol @ needing to get permission from me