# Mass Retag request? [meta-tag:synonym-request]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, meta

Would it be worth retagging questions which are making synonym requests as [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request).  From what I see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354/batch-retagging), it sounds like the mods could perform this sort of soft-tagging without bumping everything -- sorry didn't realize that this would bump questions and stopped when I noticed after the fourth question.

There are a [whole bunch](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=synonym+%2B+request) of questions which *could* be retagged, if this is deemed reasonable.  Note - for those interested that I *did not* propose the [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request).

Comment: Uh, I don't get it. The person making the synonym request was supposed to use that tag on their question in the first place. What are you requesting that we retag now? Remember that synonym requests are not the same thing as merge requests or deletion requests (also known as "burnination").

Comment: My intention was to differentiate synonym requests from other uses of [meta-tag:tag-synonyms], but maybe it's just splitting hairs.  In other words, I was checking out the [newest tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) created and thought, oh that might be reasonable.  [As opposed to seeing fire in my eyes...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97565)  :O)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't need a separate tag for synonym requests. The proper tag is [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request).

If we do a bulk retag job, the implication is that the tags are identical in meaning - they *should* be made synonyms after 90% of these jobs. The exceptions are disambiguations and the like.

The importance of making a synonym request is not as much the creation of the synonym, but the changing of all of the existing instances of a tag. And that's really just a [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request). You can simply just slap a "Please do/do not make this a synonym" in the question body, if it must explicitly be said.

Comment: Should I then propose that this tag be 'burninated'??

Answer (score 0):

If we created the [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) to categorise those requests so yes it is interesting to retag question for synonym request if they are still live: i.e. not competed or denied.

We do not need to "necromance" all synonym requests by retagging.

On another hand, I do not thing that the [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) is useful by itself since we have
[tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). Both of these are equivalent to [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request). Or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is mandatory, so [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) is just too much.